# Diferença entre VM e Containers LXC

Tags: linux, virtualbox, docker

Olá, estou procurando entender qual é a diferença entre VM e Containers LXC?

Tudo que eu leio soa um pouco abstrato e o resultado final parece ser o mesmo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Virtual Machine

Uma Virtual Machine (VM) consiste em rodar diversos Sistemas Operacionais (SOs) completos (Linux, Windows, BSD, …) em recursos de hardware compartilhados. Tais SOs podem ser diferentes em cada VM e também pode ser diferente do sistema operacional base, onde rodam as VMs. Cada kernel do Sistema Operacional virtualizado considera sua execução em um hardware comum, sendo ele genérico ou um driver hypervisor específico.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

### Containers LXC

Os Containers são isolamento de recursos: processos, sistema de arquivos, interfaces de rede e outros recursos do kernel (memória compartilhada, mutexes, semáforos, …) sendo executado dentro de um sistema operacional, com algumas limitações (CPU, memória, iops). Os Containers são comumente descritos como “chroot on steroids”. O FreeBSD jails ou o Solaris zones/containers possuem o mesmo objetivo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

A tecnologia de VMs, como o nome diz, simula uma máquina física para o OS instalado nela. Ela permite instalar qualquer OS dentro dela, independente do OS do host.
Já Containers, como o Docker, criam ambientes isolados dentro de um mesmo OS.

É possível usar uma VM Windows em um sistema linux e vice versa. Com o Docker isso não é possível. (A não ser rodando o docker dentro de uma VM).

Para criar uma VM é necessária uma imagem que inclui o OS+applicativos, que costuma ter centenas de MBs. No Docker, o ambiente pode ser criado com arquivos menores pois não precisam ter todo o OS.

O tempo de inicialização de uma VM é parecido com o de ligar um servidor, enquanto que um container pode subir em questão de segundos.

O Docker permite compartilhar a memória RAM do host enquanto que cada VM rodando aloca uma parte da memória para si, tornando inviável a execução de várias VMs simultaneamente em um desktop, por exemplo.