# Como "Docker" e "containers" (LXC, LXD) funcionam?

Tags: docker

Eu vi esta pergunta [Diferença entre VM e Containers LXC](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/96137/3635), mas o foco dela é um comparativo entre VM e containers. O que eu gostaria de saber é um pouco mais sobre containers, como Docker, LXC e LXD.

Gostaria de saber o foco de cada um e como funcionam os *containers linux*. VirtualHost tem alguma coisa haver com isto?

E esses containers são suportados apenas por linux? Ou existe outros ambientes unix-like que suportam containers?

Comment: Windows também suporta =D (pelo menos usando Docker)

Comment: @jbueno nossa eu não sabia, pensei que Docker dependece da tecnologia do nucleo Linux

Comment: Isso é recente, não sei como funciona. Mas vi no site oficial deles.

Answer (score 5):

Dê uma olhada [nesta](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/254956/what-is-the-difference-between-docker-lxd-and-lxc) resposta (inglês). Em suma:

- **LinuX Container (LXC)** consiste um meio de baixo nível para virtualizar sistemas Linux. Trabalha em nível de sistema operacional.
- **LXD** é um *hypervisor* que usa LXC por baixo dos panos. Pense nele como LXC com um ferramental mais incrementado. Por exemplo, o LXD possui uma interface HTTP REST para administração.
- **Docker** também é uma ferramenta para virtualização baseada no LXC, mas com ênfase na virtualização de aplicativos.

A grande diferença entre o LXD e o Docker é que o LXD foca em virtualizar sistemas operacionais inteiros, enquanto o Docker propõe trabalhar com um escopo menor (apenas um aplicativo).

Comment: Parece um bom caminho para entender, me tira uma duvida, isso depende exclusivamente da tecnologia dentro do nucleo linux, como funciona essa tecnologia? O @jbueno disse que docker é suportado em "estações" Windows também.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento o LXC é associado ao Linux. O que a Microsoft está fazendo é implementar o conceito de containers dentro do Windows. Essa tecnologia, 'Windows Containers', suporta as imagens do Docker.

Comment: entendi não é que o Docker roda no windows de verdade, vou ler mais a respeito, obrigado :D

Comment: Apenas uma correção na resposta acima, o Docker deixou o LXC em 2014, pra em prol de uma lib própria.