# O que são Containers e Docker?

Tags: terminologia, docker

O que são Containers e Docker na visão de um desenvolvedor?
para que são utilizados e qual a importância em em um projeto de software?

Comment: Relacionadas: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/166870/como-docker-e-containers-lxc-lxd-funcionam & https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/96137/diferen%c3%a7a-entre-vm-e-containers-lxc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Os containers do docker são visto como uma forma de virtualizar um ambiente para o desenvolvedor trabalhar e tem como finalidade a criação de um ambiente separado da sua máquina original, ou seja você virtualiza esse ambiente no docker para que as alterações que você fizer na maquina original não interfira no seu ambiente docker.

Mas o docker também agiliza muito o desenvolvimento, você pode simplesmente entrar no site deles e baixar a imagem que quer trabalhar, você instala de forma muito facil e não precisar fazer toda a configuração que levaria bastante tempo, pois boa parte já vem configurada você apenas seta alguns parâmetros e pronto usa tranquilamente.